# Where file is ignored by .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I am doing

```
git add db/schema.rb
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
db/schema.rb
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Where can I find this file is being ignored, see:

```
cat .gitignore
.project
nbproject
.redcar
cat ~/.gitignore
.idea
```

`~/.gitignore` is for global ignores.

Comment: right, there was a schema.rb, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily check what `.gitignore` rule is currently making your file ignored in your git repo with [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) (you must have git 1.8.3.3+):

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/your/file
```

(The `-v` -- verbose -- option is important to see the rule)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but this might help somebody.

If I want to see al my ignored files and I want to know what .gitignore is making them 'ignored' in the directory where I want to know this info, I run this command:

```
# Finds ignored files recursively and shows what .gitignore is ignoring them
find . -type d -exec bash -c "git check-ignore -v {}/*" \;
```

Another way:

```
# Same as before but doesn't show errors for git check-ignore
find . -type d -exec bash -c "git check-ignore -v {}/*" 2>/dev/null \;
```